# NameError: name 'fhost' is not defined

Tags: python

I need to convert a CSV Table to Dokuwiki Syntax but I need help as I always get the same error.

The Error that i always get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/etc/serverliste/csvtodokuwiki2.py", line 21, in <module>
        fhost.write(title[ii] + ": " + arr[ii] + "\n")
    NameError: name 'fhost' is not defined
```

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f = open("/etc/serverliste/server.csv", "r")

title = []
i = 0
for line in f:
    arr = line.split(";")
    if i == 0:
        title = arr
    else:
        fhost = open("/var/www/html/dokuwiki/data/pages/playground/" + arr[0], "w")
        fhost.write("<h1>" + arr[0] + "</h1><p>&nbsp;</p><p><span style=font-size:12pt>Anmerkung: Diese Seite wurde automatisch generiert und wird t&auml;glich aktualisiert. Eine manuelle &Auml;nderung dieser Seite wird hierdurch wieder r&uuml;ckg&auml;ngig gemacht.</span></p>")

    ii = 0

    for item in arr:
        if ii > (len(title) - 1):
            break

        fhost.write(title[ii] + ": " + arr[ii] + "\n")

        ii = ii + 1
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have  `fhost` only in the else part. It skips if the condition goes to `if`

**Demo:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f = open("/etc/serverliste/server.csv", "r")
title = []
i = 0
for line in f:
    arr = line.split(";")
    fhost = open("/var/www/html/dokuwiki/data/pages/playground/" + arr[0], "w")     #Declare if before `if-else` condition
    if i == 0:
        title = arr
    else:
        fhost.write("<h1>" + arr[0] + "</h1><p>&nbsp;</p><p><span style=font-size:12pt>Anmerkung: Diese Seite wurde automatisch generiert und wird t&auml;glich aktualisiert. Eine manuelle &Auml;nderung dieser Seite wird hierdurch wieder r&uuml;ckg&auml;ngig gemacht.</span></p>")

    ii = 0
    for item in arr:
        if ii > (len(title) - 1):
            break
        fhost.write(title[ii] + ": " + arr[ii] + "\n")
        ii = ii + 1
    i = i + 1
```